# Facebook iFrame tab, cut off at the bottom

Tags: facebook, iframe, tabs

I have a problem with longer image view on Mac Chrome. It is cut on the bottom. I can't check it because I do not have access to a Mac, while on my pc using Chrome it is ok. Here is a screenshot of the error. Please let me know what it could be? https://i.stack.imgur.com/umZ8y.jpg

P.S. it's just a DIV set with CSS to left 0,top 0 position; with  inside. I see it ok on Chrome, IE and FireFox' client on Chrome see error (like the image) on Safari it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

If your *Canvas Height* setting is set to "*Settable*" then you may need to use `FB.Canvas.setSize();`:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelURL : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    FB.Canvas.setSize();
};

// Do things that will sometimes call sizeChangeCallback()

function sizeChangeCallback() {
    FB.Canvas.setSize();
}
```

**BUT** this may not work because this method will be called even if the image is not fully loaded. So another solution would be:

```
window.onload = function () {
  FB.Canvas.setSize();
}
```

**NOTE:** this would override other functions that is assigned to fire on window "load". More about this in my [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/facebook-javascript-sdk-best-practices/58/#user_auto-size_option_and).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Unfortunately i use 3rd party application adn i cant change it's source code. I am only able to put HTML/CSS, so i did, but it's nothing complicated there it's really just a image as a background and one div with SWF.